# How can I launch an Automator workflow simply by clicking on its Finder icon?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I'm running Big Sur 11.7.5.

I have created a workflow with Automator (it's an AppleScript workflow, if that matters). It exists on my disk with the name "my.workflow".

I just want to double-click on "my.workflow" in the Finder and have it start running the workflow. However, when I double-click, it just launches the Automator app with that workflow inside of the editor window.

I'm sure there must be some way to run a workflow by simply double-clicking an icon, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Workflows' can only be run inside Automator itself. To make it independent, it needs to be an Application.

Open your Workflow, then from the Edit menu select Convert…
Set to Application then Save.

[image]

Comment: Aha! "Convert" is the solution. Thank you!